# Как передать значение <label> в другой <div> при изменении <input>`ов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Господа! Помогите пожалуйста )

Как передать значение label в другой div при изменении input`ов?  Выбрал к примеру chekbox - содержимое его label уходит в div в другом месте... Снял флажок, значение удалилась. А?

```html
<body>
  <input id="che1" name="che1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="che1">Самость</label>
  
  <input id="che2" name="che" type="radio">
  <label for="che2">Первое</label>
  
  <input id="che3" name="che" type="radio">
  <label for="che3">Или второе</label>

  <div class="innerHere"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="che1" name="che1" type="checkbox" onchange="onChange(this)">
<label for="che1">Или второе</label>

<div class="innerHere"></div>
<script>
    function onChange(that) {
        var inpId = that.getAttribute("id");
        var text = document.querySelector("label[for=" + inpId + "]").innerHTML;
    document.querySelector(".innerHere").innerHTML = that.checked ? text : "";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Jamshed, а как быть если у меня к примеру уже есть функция onchange="" на input`ах?

Comment: Можно вызвать эту функцию из той которая у Вас уже имеется

Comment: если хотите могу подогнать пример под Вас?

Comment: работает! ) Вот только не уходит при снятии флажка )

Comment: document.querySelector(".innerHere").innerHTML = that.checked ? text : "";

Comment: В ответе поставил проверку )

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли )

Comment: Не, из другой функции вызвать не получается )

Comment: Вам надо передать ссылку на объект, в параметрах вызова. что то на подобии  onchange="someFunction("param1", param2,  this)"

Comment: и потом в фунции someFunction("param1", param2, that)  вызвать onChange(that)

Comment: Вот я тупооой ) Я изначально вопрос не правильно поставил ) https://jsfiddle.net/m70epbat/ - мне нужно <p> вытащить в другой div )

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cu7hnxuk/

Comment: Вам надо дополнить html, там сейчас отсутсвуют теги optionic и kpb

Answer (score 1):

Этот вариант если `input` один и `innerHere`тоже

```js
const che1 = document.querySelector('#che1');
const innerHere = document.querySelector('.innerHere');
che1.addEventListener('change', function() {
  innerHere.innerHTML = (che1.checked) ? document.querySelector('#che').innerHTML : ''
})
```

```html
<input id="che1" name="che1" type="checkbox">
<label id="che" for="che1">Самость</label>


<div class="innerHere"></div>
```

---

Второй вариант с несколькоми  `input_radio`

```js
const innerHere = document.querySelector('.innerHere');

[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(function(s, i) {
  s.addEventListener('change', function() {
    innerHere.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('label')[i].innerHTML
  })
});
```

```html
<input id="che1" name="che" type="radio">
<label id="che_1" for="che1">Самость1</label>

<input id="che2" name="che" type="radio">
<label id="che_2" for="che2">Самость2</label>

<input id="che3" name="che" type="radio">
<label id="che_3" for="che3">Самость3</label>

<div class="innerHere"></div>
```

Comment: Прикольная штука получается, можно будет display : none-ом скрывать содержимое class="innerHere"... Просто и легко, но мне все таки интересно было бы с js`ом попробовать, посмотреть хотя бы) Спасибо!

Comment: Учти, `display : none` используя теряешь плавность )))))

Answer (score 1):

Сделал при условии использования `Jquery`

Мой JS

```js
$('input:radio').click(function(){
        a = $(this).attr('id');
        b = $("label[for='"+a+"']").text();
        $('.innerHere').text(b)
    });
```

```html
<input id="che1" name="che" type="radio">
<label id="che_1" for="che1">Самость1</label>
<input id="che2" name="che" type="radio">
<label id="che_2" for="che2">Самость2</label>
<input id="che3" name="che" type="radio">
<label id="che_3" for="che3">Самость3</label>
<div class="innerHere"></div>
```

Выглядит намного красивее что вам скидывали выше :)